# Asignar valor a una columna en función de otra columna string

Tags: python

Tengo una dataframe 'tia' con una columna 'Mod ascensor' el que quiero comparar para generar una nueva columna 'E-SCM-Invertido' con el valor de 1 si coincide con este valor en la columna 'Mod ascensor'

El código que he generado es:

```
SCMInv=[]
for row in tia['Mod ascensor']:
    if row=='E-SCM-Invertido':
        SCMInv=1
    else:
        SCMInv=0
tia['E-SCM-Invertido']=SCMInv
```

No consigo que me indique el valor 1, siempre me indica 0. ¿Qué error estoy cometiendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que tienes es que las asignaciones:

```
if ...:
    SCMInv=1
else:
    SCMInv=0
```

están almacenando un entero escalar en la variable `SCMInv`, que por tanto deja de ser una lista. Al terminar el bucle esa variable valdrá 1 ó 0 dependiendo de lo que hayas encontrado en la última fila. Cuando después haces:

```
tia['E-SCM-Invertido']=SCMInv
```

estarías asignando ese valor escalar a una columna. Pandas en este caso lo convierte en una asignación vectorial, repitiendo ese valor para todos los elementos de la columna.

Para arreglar tu código habría que hacer:

```
SCMInv = []
for row in tia["Mod ascensor"]:
  if row=="E-SCM-Invertido":
    SCMInv.append(1)
  else:
    SCMInv.append(0)
```

### Una solución mejor

Iterar por las filas de un dataframe nunca es la forma más eficiente, pues esta iteración la hace un bucle python que mucho más lento que hacer uso de las operaciones vectoriales que Pandas proporciona (que están implementadas en C).

La versión vectorial de este código sería:

```
tia['E-SCM-Invertido']= (tia['Mod ascensor'] == 'E-SCM-Invertido') +0
```

A la derecha de la asignación tenemos una operación vectorial, que se aplica a cada elemento del vector sin necesidad de un bucle `for`. La comparación `tia['Mod ascensor'] == 'E-SCM-Invertido'` se realiza elemento a elemento y el resultado es un vector de booleanos. Al sumar 0 al resultado, esta operación (también vectorial) suma 0 a cada booleano, dando como resultado `0` si era `False` o `1` si era `True`.

#### Demo:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Creo un dataframe de ejemplo, con valores aleatorios
casos = ["E-SCM-Invertido", "Foo", "Bar"]
data = { "Mod ascensor": [random.choice(casos) for _ in range(10)]}
tia = pd.DataFrame(data)

# El algoritmo es ahora una sola línea
tia['E-SCM-Invertido']= (tia['Mod ascensor'] == 'E-SCM-Invertido') +0
print(tia)
```

```html
      Mod ascensor  E-SCM-Invertido
0  E-SCM-Invertido                1
1              Bar                0
2  E-SCM-Invertido                1
3              Foo                0
4              Bar                0
5              Foo                0
6              Foo                0
7              Foo                0
8              Foo                0
9  E-SCM-Invertido                1
```